# Why i cannot use "int " here?

Tags: python

My interperter version is python 3.5, and when i input a floating number, the error ocurred.
This is my code:

```
a = input()
weight = int(a)
print(weight)
```

and the error is:

```
34.44
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Text/Project_SDC/Astar_Algorithm/test.py", line 2, in <module>
weight = int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '34.44'
```

so if i still want to use int type, is there any solution for the error??

Comment: `int(float(a))`

Comment: "34.44" is a float literal, so do `'float(a)` to get 34.44.  Then if you want to truncate it to an int, `int(float(a))`.

Comment: The string should only contain digits. For floats use `float`.

Comment: Because `int` doesn't work with strings of floats...

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should convert string `'34.44'` to float first, then use `int` which will make it 34 only

```
int(float(a))
```

or you can use round: `round(float(a))`